# WINE 1.3 with Amazon Kindle

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks, kindle

I am experiencing problems getting Wine/PlayOnLinux to work with my Amazon Kindle Account.

Firstly, I installed Wine/PlayOnLinux downloaded Amazon for PC and Wine picked up the exe. After installation, it took me to a registration dialog, where I entered in my amazon account details. It returned a message and said registration failed. There doesn't seem to be another screen to login with.

Is there a a bug with this, or does someone have another app where I can download my Kindles on to Ubuntu 15.10 64bit?

Comment: You couldn't have have wine-1.3 in Ubuntu 15.10 o.O I mean, you can install it, but I don't think there's a reason to prefer that ancient version. I guess you wrote it wrong. Anyway, launch the Kindle with Wine from terminal, and add to your post whatever errors you see.

Comment: Try updating to a new version of Wine by running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel`.